# Why go.mod keeps changing with go test

Tags: go, go-modules

Hi I want to pin a particular version of dependency in my `go.mod`, like

```
    github.com/dependecy v1.7.0
```

And when I run `go test` or `go build`, sometimes it gets updated to

```
    github.com/dependecy v1.8.0
```

The tricky part is sometimes it changes, and sometimes it does not. We would want to pin to an older version because the new version has a bug. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Basically any invocation of the `go` command might modify go.mod except you specify `-mod=readonly`. Note that go build and go test compile a different set of files. So go test might include additional modules which _require_ 1.8.0. If a dependency requires 1.8.0 you cannot pin it to 1.7.0 for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason why this is happening is because you might have a dependency that might have requirement for higher version of the module. From go documentation [here](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-The_main_module_and_the_build_list)

> If multiple versions of a particular module are added to the list, then at the end only the latest version (according to semantic version ordering) is kept for use in the build.

You can try the commands listed in documentation or, run `go build` with `-mod=readonly` flag. That should help you understand what might be triggering this.

Answer (score 0):

Go modules does not support multiple minor versions of same package in a single module, if added then at the end only the latest version is kept for use in the build.

You can have some dependency which have requirement of higher version and replacing the old one.

**If a module out there pushed v1.8.0 with a bug, file a bug or fork the repository as needed.**